# Hide text under screen width 860px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wrote a code for `hide` and text under screen resolution 860px.. But it doesn't work where am i did the mistake ?

**Example at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyvPXN)**

Thanks for any help guys !

```js
var width = $(window).width(), height = $(window).height();
if ((width >= 1024)) {
$('#px').show()
} else {
$('#px').hide()
}
```

```css
p {display: inline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"><p id="px">www.</p>mywebsite.com</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CSS

You just do this with pure CSS negating the need for any JavaScript or page loading. This way is much better and supported than using JavaScript

```css
@media (max-width: 860px) {
  #px {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="px">Text to be hidden under 860px</div>
```

### JavaScript / jQuery

If you do need it to be done within JavaScript/jQuery, your code is out by a small amount.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $(window).outerWidth();
  if (width <= '860') {
    $('#px').hide();
  } else {
    $('#px').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="px">Text to be hidden under 860px</div>
```

Comment: Nice thanks.. It help me.. Yeah i need it to do that with JQ cause i gonna add more functions in there..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javaScript, only use css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
#px{display: none}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
#px{display: block}
}
```